# android program to display rout between two locations

Tags: android

Does anyone know how to do google map program in android by inputing two location's name and now one can see the rout between them

Comment: Google Maps App should allow you to accomplish that

Answer (score -2):

Yeah, add code to display some HTML along the lines of

```
<a href="http://maps.google.com">Google Maps</a>
```

If you don't like that, use an iframe instead.